# Proof that $\text{Magnetic Flux Density} = {\text{Magentic Flux} \over A\sin(θ)}?$

Tags: electricity, magnetic-fields

Problem :  How is $\text{Magnetic Flux Density} = {\text{Magnetic Flux} \over A\sin(θ)}$ (this is the formula my text book has given me)

**Where $θ$ is the angle between magnetic flux lines and plane 
and $A$ is the Area**

I know that $\text{Magnetic Flux Density} = {\text{Magnetic Flux} \over A}$ but where does that $\sin(θ)$ come from ? Why is the formula multiplied by $1 \over \sin(θ)$  ?

thanks in advance

Comment: The element of flux is  $|A| {\bf n}\cdot {\bf B}$ where $|A|$ is the area and ${\bf n}$ is the unit normal to the surface.  This is  $|A| \cos \theta$. For some reason your book uses $90-\theta$ hence the $\sin\theta$.

Comment: @mike stone how does the dot product of n.B gives us cos(θ) in the first place?

Comment: Is is not just the definition of the dot product?  ${\bf n}\cdot {\bf B}= |{\bf n}| |{\bf B}| \cos \theta$?  Geometrically its just that it's only when the area is face-on that you see all of it. If it's at an angle you only see a fraction $\cos \theta$  of it. Edge on, there is no area for the field to penentrate.